# Why some of the android applications include "Press Back again to quit" feature

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of Android applications recently that they display a Toast saying "Press Back again to quit" when back pressed.

We can implement this feature easily just by keeping a boolean when back pressed. But is there any specific reason to implement this feature ??

Comment: Can I know why it is downvoted?? I am just curious to know if the feature is to do anything with activity/fragment backstack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is there any specific reason to implement this feature ?

IMHO, no.

I have seen two use cases for this in apps that I have used:

1. The app has important UI down by where the BACK button may be, and they are worried that users will accidentally tap the BACK button. I would recommend they not put important small tap targets down there in the first place.
2. The app is using BACK to mean something other than "return to the previous UI state", like a file manager using BACK to navigate up a directory tree. IMHO, that's a mis-use of the BACK button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, should be pretty obvious, for example you would implement this if you don't want your user to accidentally exit the app. If the navigation hierarchy of your app is big enough there is a significant chance that the user presses back one too many times. Such a feature is a simple fix for that. Although I wouldn't recommend it if it is not really necessary for your app since such a feature can also be annoying pretty quickly...